# TensorFlow works although it is not installed

Tags: tensorflow, keras, installation, deep-learning, anaconda

After much trouble installing `TensorFlow` under Anaconda, I removed Anaconda completely and installed it again (64-bit Anaconda3 under Windows 10 with Python 3.8). To my great surprise, I can now import `TensorFlow` from Jupyter Notebook even though I have not installed `TensorFlow` under Anaconda yet and it is listed as "not installed" in the base environment. What magic is going on here?

[image]

Comment: @M.Innat `installation` is an existing valid tag on SO.

Comment: What do you mean **listed as "not installed" in the base environment**? Have you tested with `pip list`? or just check the installed packages from the Anaconda UI?

Comment: Only Anaconda UI. You are right, `pip list` shows `tensorflow`, though I don't believe I ever installed it using `pip`... Should I do anything to clean this mess?

Comment: You can also check with `conda list`, it will show you a `Channel` column for corresponding installed packages. That probably will show you the installed `tf` whether comes from `pypi` or `conda-forge`.

Comment: @M.Innat No, `conda list` does not show it...

Comment: Doesn't show what? For me, if I execute `conda list`, I get `tensorflow  2.4.1 pypi_0   pypi` - which means my `tf` was installed via pip, and that's true as I did install with pip.

Comment: @M.Innat `tensorflow` does not appear in the output of `conda list` for me.

Answer (score 1):

As we know anaconda uses the `conda` package manager, so executing the `conda list` would print out the available installed packages. It also executes the list of packages installed via the `python` package manager (via `pip`).

```
conda list 

# Name                    Version                 Build        Channel

ca-certificates           2020.12.5            h5b45459_0    conda-forge
cachetools                4.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
cairo                     1.16.0            hba8bd2f_1007    conda-forge
certifi                   2020.12.5        py38haa244fe_1    conda-forge
tensorflow                2.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
```

Now, if you open the Anaconda Navigator, you would also find the above information. For example, `pip` installed packages on the left, `conda` install the package on right.

[image]

Now, if I uninstall Anaconda, the packages installed via `pip` would be still there, and reinstall the Anaconda wouldn't do any issue. However, I assumed that you followed the official installation guideline from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu).

Comment: `tensorflow` does not appear in the output of `conda list` for me.

Comment: yes, I get that in the question comment section, that why I showed you here to open the anaconda navigator and see if you could find any information there. It's hard to debug from here.

Comment: I never try to install `tf` via conda. When you install `tf` from conda, is it something `conda install tensorflow` or just a UI that showed an option to install `tf`? I'm sure if you did the second one, using UI, the anaconda install `tf` from pip.  And probably that's why, after removing the anaconda it didn't remove pip packages.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, `tensorflow` appears without a checkmark on the left, i.e. it shows as not installed in the navigator.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning you can also use the `pip show tensorflow` command and see the `Location` info. Thus you may have a clear idea of where is `tf` located with its packages.